# d3js: How to stop all transitions?

Tags: ajax, d3.js, transition, turbolinks

I have a web-application with d3js and turbolinks (ajax navigation).

Some of my pages contains a long-run transitions (over 100s), so when a part of the page was being reloaded with AJAX all the transitions from previous page are still running.

How can I **completely** remove **all** the transitions from the original page?

There is an event called "*page:before-unload*" in turbolinks so I'm planning to use it for the cleanup.

Comment: You just need to call `.transition()` on all elements that have a transition attached to them.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I'm seeking a universal solution if it exists.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "universal solution" -- this will work in every case.

Comment: It will work in every case only when I have an access to the source code and I store refs to all the transitions somewhere. I prefer a solution which will work on any d3js pages (not only mine) and clean all the transitions when SVG/canvas/html is being destroyed.

Comment: When you remove an element, all the transitions attached to it will also be removed. So if you remove the SVG/canvas/whatever, all the transition will automatically go away.

Comment: Nope. It's not seems true. My jsfiddle with examples is below. The answer by @Hy is correct.

Comment: It doesn't work in your jsfiddle because there's no element with ID `element1`.

Comment: There is, at line no 1.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right -- too obvious :) The problem in this case is that you're keeping a reference to `rect` in the closure that you're using to initialise the transition. So by removing the surrounding element you're not really removing it because `rect` still exists in a function that is being executed (the running transition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comments, I think this will work:

```
d3.selectAll('*').transition();
```

But the transitions will be destroyed when the svg/canvas is destroyed, as Lars Kotthoff said, so there's no need for this if you're destroying the svg/canvas.

Comment: Note that this will be quite slow with lots of elements.

Comment: I don't see any way to get all the elements which have transitions attached but it still better than modify (not mine) working code and store all the transitions somewhere. 
Maybe there is another way?

Comment: Actually I can add a class something like "loopedTransitionElement" and then query all the elements by `d3.selectAll('.loopedTransitionElement').transition()` to stop all the transitions that I need to be stopped.